# Maximum number of attachments in E-Mail

Tags: email

Is there an upper limit on the number of attachments one can send in a single e-mail message? I am coding an application to act as an e-mail forwarding service which receives delivery requests and stores them in a database for later dispatching, and it would come in very handy if I knew beforehand that sending more than, say, 32 attachments is not supported by the e-mail protocols. Is there any such limit?

Comment: What client are you useing to send emails?

Comment: It will be a given SMTP server about which I know nothing at this point.

Comment: I know that there is a list of RFCs which talk about things such as maximum length of e-mail addresses and so on, but I can't remember the number right now. I'm sure that they would be the correct place to look for canonical answer.

Comment: If I'm reading the [FRC 5321](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-4.5.3.1) correctly (section 4.5.3.1.7. seems relevant), then there should be no limit to number of attachments in an e-mail. Any limit should be only imposed by implementation.

Comment: True, but the majority of ISP's have their own interpretation of this as they each have their own spam servers... I'm suffering from one at the moment who has set a (low) limit to the number of emails you can receive in an hour... ARGH!

Answer (score 2):

As @AndrejaKo identifies [rfc5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.5.3.1) states there should be no limit to the number of attachments in theory but implementations may vary as @HaydnWVN points out. More likely to hit the limit for the email size (e.g. [Virgin Media](http://help.virginmedia.com/system/selfservice.controller?CONFIGURATION=1002&PARTITION_ID=1&TIMEZONE_OFFSET=&USERTYPE=1&CMD=VIEW_ARTICLE&ARTICLE_ID=37906) will return emails larger than 20MB and [GMail limit is 25MB](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=8770))